# Most efficient way to find next increment in a big number

Tags: java, algorithm, performance, coding-efficiency

I have a number `long nbr = 10000`. I am increasing and decreasing this, and the amount to increase or decrease depends on its value. If `nbr > x`, then nbr += xx, if `nbr > y`, then nbr += yy, etc. Depending on other factors, the increment values (xx, yy, etc) will change and also the limits where the increment value changes (x,y, etc) will change. I want a function public int increaseNbr(int nbr) that returns an incremented number according to the above logic, and does this as efficiently as possible. Currently I am implementing it like the following but I have a feeling it is not very efficient.

```
private TreeMap<Integer, Integer> aboveNbr_increment_map;

private Integer getIncrementValueAboveNbr(int nbr) {

    // finds the valid increment below a certain price
    Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> entry = aboveNbr_increment_map.lastEntry();

    while (entry != null) {

        if (price>=entry.getKey()) {
            return entry.getValue();
        }

        entry = aboveNbr_increment_map.lowerEntry(entry.getKey());
    }

    // otherwise return the lowest increment size
    return aboveNbr_increment_map.get(aboveNbr_increment_map.firstKey());
}

    public Integer getNextNbrAbove(int nbr) {

        return nbr + this.getIncrementValueAboveNbr(nbr));
    }
```

Comment: Never check the result of a `compareTo`-call agains -1 or 1. The contract for `Comparable.compareTo` allows *any* negative number if this object is lower then the supplied object and *any* positive number if this object is greater. Apart from that: Does performance matter most or do you rather want a concise and readable solution? In what range are the prices? Is it correct that they are integers?

Comment: Performance is a priority. Thanks for pointing out the compareTo issue, actually that was a typo on my part. The range of numbers is between 0 and 1,000,000 and I repopulate the map sometimes.

Comment: If repopulation is done seldom and your method is called very frequently you might consider precalculating an `int[] incvals` of length 1,000,000 containing the increment value for each possible nbr and calculate the result using `nbr + incvals[nbr]` with *O(1)* complexity. This approach needs about 4 MiB of RAM though. Additionally using that approach the method code becomes very short and is very likely inlined sooner or later so that even the method call can become no-cost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it in logarithmic time using [`floorEntry`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html#floorEntry(K)) by finding lower-bound.

```
private TreeMap<Integer, Integer> aboveNbr_increment_map;

private Integer getIncrementValueAboveNbr(int nbr) {

    Entry<Integer, Integer> entry = aboveNbr_increment_map.floorEntry(nbr);

    if(entry != null) {
        return nbr + entry.getValue();
    }

    return aboveNbr_increment_map.get(aboveNbr_increment_map.firstKey());
}
```

Before this store the key-value in `TreeMap` like this -

```
aboveNbr_increment_map.put(x + 1, xx);
aboveNbr_increment_map.put(y + 1, yy);
```

You need to store `x + 1` instead of `x` because `floorEntry` returns the greatest key less than or equal to the given key. And here we are increaming when `nbr` value is `> x`.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 2):

Your TreeMap approach has a complexity of log(N), where N is the number of boundaries. This may be perfectly acceptable if the number of boundaries is small enough.

You mentioned in the comments that your number space is fairly restricted. At only one million possible numbers, you could also build a lookup table (array) using number as the index. This would give you O(1), but the lookup table does incure its own cost to build and its memory consumption.

Depending on the number of lookups between table changes, the lookup table may be faster or slower.

Unless your program spends a sizable portion of its runtime calling getIncrementValueAboveNbr() you are probably wasting your time though. Profile whatever uses the method and only if this reveals a large portion of time spent there consider rewriting it.